# Remove watermark by merging two videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay, mask

I have actually two videos, one in high quality but with watermark and the other in poor quality without watermark. They are not synchronized.

I would like to do something like the `removelogo` filter of ffmpeg but instead to simply interpolate like `removelogo` I would like to extract a part of a frame of the poor quality video to put it on the highest quality video with a mask to hide the watermark.

Unfortunately the two videos are not synchronized and I would like to synchronize with the audio stream.

Is it possible to do that with ffmpeg?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the sync off by a constant factor or does it grow as the duration elapses?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question. I need to find an offset to synchronize. I am thinking to a autocorrelation on audio stream but I do not know if ffmpeg can do that.

Comment: For example, is consistently it out of sync by 3 seconds, or is it out of sync by 3 seconds at the beginning and 6 seconds at the end?